# Is there a way to get a specific number of plots in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a grid of 13 graphs. But due to the nature of the code, I have to say:

`fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=5, figsize=(16,10))`

This creates a grid of 15 plots. While the last two remain unused. 
Is there a way to plot only 13 plots?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 13 is a prime number, this means that you cannot find a grid shape that will fit all plots without any white space. The only way you can use is to plot a single row of 13 plots, otherwise you have to find a compromise like 4x4, 5x3 or 3x5